# MySQL Workbench dialog.dll for PAM connection

Tags: mysql-workbench, mariadb

**Question:** How can I tell MySQL Workbench from where it should load plugins for a connection?

I'm trying to connect my MySQL Workbench on Windows to a MariaDB where the user is connected to an IPA with PAM.

When I try to open the connection, I'm receiving following error message: ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'dialog' cannot be loaded.

When I save this dialog.dll from MariaDB in a folder and call mysql.exe with the option `--plugin-dir "C:\MySQL\Workbench\modules"` I can successfully open a connection.

The dll-File cannot be loaded with "Scripting" -> "Install Plugin/Module".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of "Procmon.exe" (process of MySQL Workbench) I found out, that the dialog.dll is looked for in the following path:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\plugin

[Procmon Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh8wF.png)

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 and try to connect to MariaDB 10.1.24, so it's a little confusing, that it's looking for in the shown directory.

But with the dialog.dll placed in this directory, the connection is now working.

Comment: Hmm, which part is loading this lib? The MySQL server, MySQL Workbnech, MariaDB?

Comment: The MySQL Workbench is loading this lib.

Comment: I see. This is actually a client auth plugin as described on the [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/development-pluggable-authentication/) site, which refers to the [pluggable authentication chapter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pluggable-authentication.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Where did you find the dll?