# Authentication plugin 'auth_gssapi_client' cannot be loaded

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing a program for a school project using python and MySQL. When I try to connect python with MySQL this error pops up `Authentication plugin 'auth_gssapi_client' cannot be loaded` Does someone know how to fix it? Im on windows 10.

I tried several things recommended by other posts but they all didnt work.

Here's one of them:
[MySQL Workbench dialog.dll for PAM connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624357/mysql-workbench-dialog-dll-for-pam-connection/44720069#44720069)

Thanks in advance

Heres my code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='quiz',
                                     user='root',
                                     password='1234')
except Error as e:
print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
if connection.is_connected():
    connection.close()
    print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: The first question is: do you want to use kerberos authentication in the first place? If not, then change the user's authentication type in mysql to use simple password hashing. If you do want to use kerberos authentication, then you should configure that properly and not use username and password pair.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your response, Where can I disable/remove the kerberos auth? I dont think I will need it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60693487/5389997

Comment: @Shadow I still get the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

This module is installed together with MariaDB for versions 10.5 going forward. for prior modules, you will have to install it separately. So for my case I uninstalled the previous version and installed 10.5.11